# Looking for Go equivalent of scanf

Tags: go

I'm looking for the Go equivalent of scanf().
I tried with following code:

```
  1 package main
  2 
  3 import (
  4     "scanner"
  5     "os"
  6     "fmt"
  7 )
  8 
  9 func main() {
 10     var s scanner.Scanner
 11     s.Init(os.Stdin)
 12     s.Mode = scanner.ScanInts
 13     tok := s.Scan()
 14     for tok != scanner.EOF {
 15         fmt.Printf("%d ", tok)
 16         tok = s.Scan()
 17     }
 18     fmt.Println()
 19 }
```

I run it with input from a text with a line of integers.
But it always output -3 -3 ...

And how to scan a line composed of a string and some integers?
Changing the mode whenever encounter a new data type?

The Package documentation:

> Package scanner
>
> A general-purpose scanner for UTF-8
>   encoded text.

But it seems that the scanner is not for general use.

Updated code:

```
func main() {
    n := scanf()
    fmt.Println(n)
    fmt.Println(len(n))
}

func scanf() []int {
    nums := new(vector.IntVector)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    str, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    for err != os.EOF {
        fields := strings.Fields(str)
        for _, f := range fields {
            i, _ := strconv.Atoi(f)
            nums.Push(i)
        }   
        str, err = reader.ReadString('\n')
    }   
    r := make([]int, nums.Len())
    for i := 0; i < nums.Len(); i++ {
        r[i] = nums.At(i)
    }   
    return r
}
```

Improved version:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "io"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "strconv"
    "container/vector"
)

func main() {
    n := fscanf(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println(len(n), n)
}

func fscanf(in io.Reader) []int {
    var nums vector.IntVector
    reader := bufio.NewReader(in)
    str, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    for err != os.EOF {
        fields := strings.Fields(str)
        for _, f := range fields {
            if i, err := strconv.Atoi(f); err == nil {
                nums.Push(i)
            }   
        }   
        str, err = reader.ReadString('\n')
    }   
    return nums
}
```

Comment: To get good answers, you need to make your questions easy to answer. For example, code that can easily be copied, pasted, and compiled. The Go complier doesn't accept line numbers; don't put them in your sample code.

Comment: Maybe this didn't exist when originally posted, but go has fmt.Scanf that works just like C scanf getting from stdin:

var number int
fmt.Scanf("%d",&number)

Comment: Oh my gosh!  I have been trying for hours to get a good reader from stdin.  Man, I just couldn't figure out how to write it out.  Thanks so much for posting your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your updated code was much easier to compile without the line numbers, but it was missing the package and import statements.

Looking at your code, I noticed a few things. Here's my revised version of your code.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "container/vector"
)

func main() {
    n := scanf(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println(len(n), n)
}

func scanf(in io.Reader) []int {
    var nums vector.IntVector
    rd := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    str, err := rd.ReadString('\n')
    for err != os.EOF {
        fields := strings.Fields(str)
        for _, f := range fields {
            if i, err := strconv.Atoi(f); err == nil {
                nums.Push(i)
            }
        }
        str, err = rd.ReadString('\n')
    }
    return nums
}
```

I might want to use any input file for `scanf()`, not just `Stdin`; `scanf()` takes an `io.Reader` as a parameter.

You wrote: `nums := new(vector.IntVector)`, where `type IntVector []int`. This allocates an integer slice reference named `nums` and initializes it to zero, then the `new()` function allocates an integer slice reference and initializes it to zero, and then assigns it to `nums`. I wrote: `var nums vector.IntVector`, which avoids the redundancy by simply allocating an integer slice reference named `nums` and initializing it to zero.

You didn't check the `err` value for `strconv.Atoi()`, which meant invalid input was converted to a zero value; I skip it.

To copy from the vector to a new slice and return the slice, you wrote:

```
r := make([]int, nums.Len())
for i := 0; i < nums.Len(); i++ {
    r[i] = nums.At(i)
}
return r
```

First, I simply replaced that with an equivalent, the `IntVector.Data()` method: `return nums.Data()`. Then, I took advantage of the fact that `type IntVector []int` and avoided the allocation and copy by replacing that by: `return nums`.

Comment: Thanks!
1. From the Language Specification: "When memory is allocated to store a value, either through a declaration or make() or new() call, and no explicit initialization is provided, the memory is given a default initialization". Then what's the point of new()?

2. I noticed "type IntVector []int" for the first time. Go is so different from C++. And as IntVector is type int[], is the function Data() redundant?

Answer (score 0):

This example always reads in a line at a time and returns the entire line as a string. If you want to parse out specific values from it you could.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    value :=    Input("Please enter a value: ")
    trimmed := strings.TrimSpace(value)
    fmt.Printf("Hello %s!\n", trimmed)
}

func Input(str string) string { 
        print(str) 
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin) 
        input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n') 
        return input 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest release of Go (2010-05-27) has added two functions to the `fmt` package: [`Scan()`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scan) and [`Scanln()`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanln). They don't take any pattern string. like in C, but checks the type of the arguments instead.

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "os"
   "container/vector"
)

func main() {
    numbers := new(vector.IntVector)
    var number int
    n, err := fmt.Scan(os.Stdin, &number)
    for n == 1 && err == nil {
       numbers.Push(number)
       n, err = fmt.Scan(os.Stdin, &number)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", numbers.Data())
}
```

Comment: Yes. I'll try to remember to update the answer on the next release.